# Where should I put this query to access it from the entity?

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-3.2

I have two entities with relationship One Donacion Many Pajuelas.
Now I have it in DonacionRepository as:

```
public function getPajuelasReservadas($idDonacion)
        {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();

            $consulta = $em->createQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(p) 
                     FROM EntidadBundle:Pajuela p JOIN p.donacion d 
                     WHERE d.id = :idDonacion AND p.reservada = TRUE"
            )
            ->setParameter("idDonacion", $idDonacion);

            return $consulta->getResult();
        }
```

I would like to access this query from a donation entity, without having to use `$idDonacion.`

Something like: `$donation->getPajuelasReservadas();`

What is the right way to do this? Thank you

Comment: use a Doctrine Criteria and make a business method in the entity itself

Comment: Thank you! http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: let me know if you need some example